# How do I use JMeter properties

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a Java Request in Apache JMeter.  So I create a jar with the appropriate class.  While I can get this to execute if I place the jar in JMETER_HOME/lib, I do not want to pollute the distribution of jmeter with my jars.  I've tried using my own properties file with the -p option.  I've tried editing JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.properties (not ideal, but better than nothing). In both cases I've tried several variations of all of search_paths, user.classpath, and plugin_dependency_path. For example:

- user.classpath=/tmp/myjmeter/lib
- user.classpath=/c/tmp/myjmeter/lib
- user.classpath=\tmp\myjmeter\lib
- user.classpath=C:\tmp\myjmeter\lib

I've also tried explicitly including the jar:
user.classpath=C:\tmp\myjmeter\lib\myjmeter.jar

In every case, I get in the Java Request:

> Classname not found in classpath, ensure you add the required jar and
> restart.

And, yes, I restarted JMeter with every attempt.
What am I doing wrong?
Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally you can override JMeter properties in *user.properties* file
2. If you want to use `-p` function you will need to copy there everything (default values) from the *jmeter.properties* file as well
3. If you want to pass **additional** properties file you should be using `-q` option

With regards to "where to place" your jar as per [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) article:

> The compiled class needs to be placed in /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation. Preferably, place it in .jar form so JMeter can automatically pick it up. Otherwise, you’ll need to amend the JMeter classpath.

And as per [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath):

> If you don't want to put JMeter plugin jars in the lib/ext directory, then define the property search_paths in jmeter.properties.

In case you don't want to modify *jmeter.properties* - use any of the above options. It's also possible to [override the property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter.bat -Jsearch_paths=C:\tmp\myjmeter\lib -t /path/to/testplan.jmx
```

Example custom classes for Java Request sampler: https://github.com/aboyfromipanema/java-sampler-rsa-encryption/tree/main/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/scripting

and the ones which come with JMeter: https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.5/src/protocol/java/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test